# parse_str syntax errors after upgrading from PHP 7.4 to 8.0

Tags: php, php-8

After updating to PHP8, my site has started crashing with the error

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: parse_str() expects exactly 2 arguments, 1                                                                        given

I believe it some change in the php 8 syntax, but I am not sure. I used to use php 7.4

The problematic line is:

> $url_vars = parse_str($parse_url['query'] ?? 0);

The section of the problematic script is below:

```
        if ( $referrer !== FALSE && $referrer !== '' && stripos($referrer, '://') )
    {
            $parse_url      =       parse_url($referrer);
            $domain         =       $parse_url['host'];
            $query          =       $parse_url['query'] ?? 0;
            $dotdomain      =       '.'.$domain;

            if ( strlen($parse_url['query'] ?? 0) >= 1 )
            {
                    $url_vars = parse_str($parse_url['query'] ?? 0);

                    if (FALSE === empty($url_vars['q']))
                    {
                            $utm_keyword = $url_vars['q'] ?? 0;
                    }
            }
```

Can someone more familiar with php 8 see any obvious error on the code above?

Comment: Obvious error is obvious. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php especially where it says :  `8.0.0 result is no longer optional.`. Move `$url_vars` inside of the function as the function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of PHP 8.0 the second parameter, *result*, is no longer optional and is **required**.

**result** should be the variable you want to place your output into.

You can view the changelog on the [official parse_str documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
parse_str($parse_url['query'] ?? 0, $url_vars);
```